# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (10,13,8,11,6,14,9,12,7,15)'

Tags: mysql

I don't get it, this line should work perfectly fine, yet it doesn't. For some reason I am unable to understand why? Can anyone see what I'm missing.

```
$resclients=$mysqli->query("SELECT id,client_name FROM clients WHERE id = IN ($result)");
```

Comment: without equal `WHERE id  IN ($result)`

Comment: OOOP! I completely missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct SQL query in your case is:

```
SELECT id,client_name FROM clients WHERE id IN ($result)
```

as the SQL `IN` syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Jaco! Thanks!

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 9 minutes" :(

Comment: All the people that posted an answer here, deserve to be marked with a green mark, but the system allows only one to standout so I select @Jaco as the best answer. Thx to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$resclients=$mysqli->query("SELECT id,client_name FROM clients WHERE id IN ($result)");
```